# how to permanently change host name

Tags: server

I've read through several articles on how to do this, but it seems every time I edit "/etc/hosts"  then restart my server it reverts back to the previous host names. I'm running 16.04.2 LTS

I would just like it to point to my server IP, as when I'm trying to install wordpress + lamp it installs it to the http://freeddns.noip.com I had setup.

hope this is enough information. thanks.

Comment: Host name on the server is NOT the same as registering a domain name. To set the host name on the server use `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname $new_hostname`

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: To permanently change hostname edit the hostname manually from 
sudo gedit /etc/hostname /etc/hosts

and restart.

Answer (score 11):

You need to edit the /etc/hosts and the /etc/hostname file as well. The /etc/hosts file maps IP addresses to hostnames and the /etc/hostname file contains only the hostname. After editing the /etc/hosts file, edit the /etc/hostname file and write your new hostname in it. To apply changes:

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
```

You can also use the following command to change the hostname:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname new_host_name
```

Comment: Ok, I got the /etc/hostname working now. But what can I change the /etc/hosts to so that it points to my server IP and apache installs and shows up there. right now this is the error I'm getting. 
root@myhostname:~# sudo systemctl start apache2
sudo: unable to resolve host myhostname

Comment: See the following links:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36009/how-can-i-configure-etc-hosts-file-to-point-to-apache-web-server

Comment: **Noisy_Botnet** It's probable that **@aRog121** wants to change his domain name, not the host name...  He'll have to do DNS changes instead...

Comment: I'm basing my problem off of this: https://www.tecmint.com/install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-lamp/ it doesn't install anything to the server ip, it only shows this: https://i.imgur.com/5asMWvv.png

Comment: This works temporarily, but not permanently, at least on EC2. Even though I ran these commands, after I did a `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade; apt-get dist-upgrade; reboot`, I found my EC2 Ubuntu instance had reset it's hostname to the default "ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx".

Comment: changes don't get applied